# C# MVC: Encoding a png, jpg, or pdf return value to prevent XSS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, security, encoding, xss

Suppose I have an `C#` MVC app which has a controller method that returns one of 3 content types:  `image png,  image jpeg, or application pdf`.  I have read that it is possible to have images that contain `XSS` payloads.  What would be the best way to Encode/escape these return contents so they aren't vulnerable to `XSS`?  The controller method looks like this:

```
string contentType = "image/png";
                    MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
                    if (ImageFormat == null || ImageFormat == "")
                    {
                        image.Save(mem, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (ImageFormat.ToUpper() == "PNG") image.Save(mem, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                        if (ImageFormat.ToUpper() == "JPEG")
                        {
                            image.Save(mem, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                            contentType = "image/jpeg";
                        }
                    }
                    mem.Position = 0;
                    mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    return this.Image(mem, contentType);
```

Where Image is defined the following class here:

```
using …

    namespace x.Classes
    {
        public static class ControllerExtensions
        {
            public static ImageResult Image(this Controller controller, Stream imageStream, string contentType)
            {
                return new ImageResult(imageStream, contentType);
            }        
       }
    }
```

And the OutputStream is written to using:

```
using …
namespace x.Classes
{
    public class ImageResult : ActionResult
    {
        public ImageResult(Stream imageStream, string contentType)
        {
            if (imageStream == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("imageStream");
            if (contentType == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("contentType");
           this.ImageStream = imageStream;
           this.ContentType = contentType;
       }
       public Stream ImageStream { get; private set; }
       public string ContentType { get; private set; }
       public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
       {
           if (context == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
           HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
           response.ContentType = this.ContentType;
           byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
           while (true)
           {
               int read = this.ImageStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
               if (read == 0)
                   break;
               response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
           }
           response.End();
       }
   }
}
```

Is there a way for me to escape/encode the buffer that is getting written to the OutputStream here:`

```
response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
```

To protect against `XSS` attacks?    For example if this were `HTML` that was being returned:

```
response.OutputStream.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(buffer), 0, read);
```

But we know we are returning a jpeg, pdf, or png which means `Html` encode won't work here.  So what do we use to safely escape/encode an image/pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time you have `buffer` ready, it's too late. The same as with HTML, you want to context-sensitively encode any *user input* in those files, not the whole thing.

Now, with images this doesn't make much sense in the context of XSS, an image is rendered by an image renderer, and not as html, so there won't be any javascript to be run. The general best practice for uploaded images is to process them on the server and save them as a new image, because this removes all unnecessary things, but it has its risks as well if your processor itself is the target of an attack.

SVG for example is a different beast, SVG can have code in it, as can PDF. But again, PDFs will be open on the client with a PDF viewer, not in the context of the web application even if the PDF viewer is the browser itself (the browser hopefully separates Javascript in the PDF from the web page even if the origin is the same).

But javascript in a PDF can still be an issue for the client. Javascript running in a PDF may do harmful things, the simplest of which is consume client resources (ie. DoS of some sort), or it may try to break out of the PDF context somehow exploiting a viewer vulnerability. So the attack would be that one user uploads a malicious PDF for others to download. I think the best you can do against this is scan uploaded files for malware (which you should do anyway).

If you are generating all of this from user input (images, PDFs), then the libraries you use should take care of properly encoding values so that a malicious user can't inject code in a PDF. When the PDF is already generated, you can't "fix" it anymore, user input is mixed with code.

Also make sure to set the following header in responses (along with the correct Content-Type of course):
`X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`

Comment: mvc how to prevent PDF Injection leads to Cross-site Scripting?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to encode the images themselves, you need to encode/escape the links to the images.

For example:

<a href="image.url.png?logout">Link Title</a>

where `image.url.png?logout` comes from user input.

You would url encode `image.url.png?logout` as `image.url.png%3Flogout` so that it is rendered useless to an attacker.

Comment: But in this case there is no link to the image.   The image itself is the entire result/response that is being streamed to the client/caller.  I'm overriding the mvc action result with a custom defined image result.  In this case I do not believe there is any html being returned to the client.

Comment: XSS attacks usually take place on HTML pages, not on images. Your only issue with images would be if someone could upload to you images that are harmful due to image decoder issues. Also, PDFs might be exploitable.

Comment: Note that the encoding above does not protect against `javascript:`, and PDFs can contain javascript, but I think that runs independent from the web app context even if open in the browser, so it has less (~zero) effect on the web application (but you might still want to avoid it for other reaosns, eg. client DoS).

Comment: From what I've been reading XSS attacks can be made through the image metadata, comments, or extracted tags.   So I think I need to find a way to sanatize that.  I think my setting of content type protects me from browser content sniffing attacks, where the image is really just an html file with an image file extension.   I'm also returning .pdfs which I don't know what kind of xss vulnerabilities those have.

Comment: @Engelbart User input in those fields only counts if you write them in your HTML somewhere. In that case, there needs to be HTML encoding where you write them. If you write them into Javascript, you need Javascript encoding, but again, the same as a standard web app. I thought the question was about injection in the above formats themselves.

Comment: mvc how to prevent PDF Injection leads to Cross-site Scripting?